# Change the "modified date" of a folders (in possibly powershell)

Tags: windows, script, powershell, sorting, date-modified

From time to time, when I force-shutdown a Windows Server 2003 machine  (I have no choice), the folders contained in a certain directory all change their 'modified date' to the current date.

Luckily, inside each of these folders, the files are all with the correct 'modified date'.

One of these files I want to copy the "modified (or created) date" with is a .jdf file that each of the folders has inside.

I need help to create a script in PowerSell.

I found this PS1 script that almost does the job:

```
Get-ChildItem $root | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object{

# get the oldest file for the current directory object
$oldest = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object LastWriteTime -Last 1

if($oldest)
{
# oldest object found, set current directory LastWriteTime
$_ | Set-ItemProperty -Name CreationTime -Value $oldest.LastWriteTime 
$_ | Set-ItemProperty -Name LastWriteTime -Value $oldest.LastWriteTime
}
else
{
# current directory is empty, directory LastWriteTime is left unchanged
Write-Warning "Directory '$($_.FullName)' is empty, skiping..."
}
}
```

The problem is that the last modified object inside the folders sometimes are subfolders that also get the current date as 'modified date'.
How can I make it look the files inside the folder and not the folders?

Comment: Your aim is a bit unclear for me: what the desired script should effect _exactly_?  (Please don't comment; [edit] your question rather.) However, `NTFS` date and time stamp for a particular folder changes whenever an object (file or folder) is either created or deleted inside it.

Comment: @JosefZ: I just edited the post adding a script. I hope it is clearer now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem $root |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
Foreach-Object{
    
    $oldest = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName |
        Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer } |
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
    Select-Object -Last 1

    if($oldest)
    {
        $_ | Set-ItemProperty -Name CreationTime -Value $oldest.LastWriteTime 
        $_ | Set-ItemProperty -Name LastWriteTime -Value $oldest.LastWriteTime
    }
    else
    {
        # current directory is empty, directory LastWriteTime is left unchanged
        Write-Warning "Directory '$($_.FullName)' is empty, skiping..."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whereas `Get-ChildItem $root -directory` gives the same result as

```
Get-ChildItem $root | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}
```

you could try (I don't know `PS` verbose syntax)

```
Get-ChildItem $root -file
```

or even

```
gci $root -file
```

Not sure whether your script remainder needs improvement...

Comment: I tried adding "-directory", I get an error: 
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'directory'.
At line:1 char:31
+ Get-ChildItem $root -directory  <<<< | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object{

Comment: What version of PowerShell???  Use: `(Get-Host).Version`.